# In which folder on PC (Windows 10) does load_data() save a dataset in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In which folder on PC (Windows 10) does

```
dataset_name.load_data()
```

save the dataset, so that I can use it further? For example:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the download folder is `C:\Users\<your_username>\.keras\datasets`

After I run the following code, I can see the following files in that folder:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar100
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')
```

[image: cifar100 dataset]

If not then it's wherever your `.keras\datasets` folder is located.